# WebRequest Not Working

Tags: c#, json, wcf, webrequest

The following code returns an Error in WinForms and Windows Phone 8 applications.

**Code**

```
    var jsonData = "jsonStringGoesHere";
    var uri = new Uri("urlGoesHere");
    var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    webRequest.Method = "POST";
    webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
    webRequest.ContentLength = jsonData.Length;
    webRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(ar =>
    {
        try
        {
            using (var os = webRequest.EndGetRequestStream(ar))
            {
                var postData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonData);
                os.Write(postData, 0, postData.Length);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }

        webRequest.BeginGetResponse(
            ar2 =>
            {
                try
                {
                    using (var response = webRequest.EndGetResponse(ar2))
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        var received = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                }
            }, null);
    }, null);
```

**Error**
In WinForms: `[System.Net.WebException] = {"The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."}`

In WP8 `The remote server returned an error: NotFound`.

The WCF Services are working fine as I have made them work in Fiddler and in other types of applications such as Android/iPhone.

Why won't this work?

Comment: Your server doesn't like you.  Compare the requests in Fiddler.

Comment: I have compared. They are exactly the same.

Comment: WHYYYYY WON'T THIS WORK :(:(:(:(:((:

Comment: There must be something different.  Check the Headers ect are the same. If you call the method from Fiddlers Composer will it work?  Can you share your URL?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share the URL but when I make the request in Fiddler, the JSON body is exactly the same AND the headers are the same too in that in the C# code, I have using UTF-8 and application/json... same as the Fiddler request.... It just makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly I think I was running into something similar.  I thought it had to do with the ContentLength but I don't remember really.

Here is the code I eventually used.  Not sure if it helps.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/json";
string json = BuildJSON(TestConvert(tests));
var enc = new UTF8Encoding(false);
request.ContentLength = enc.GetByteCount(json);
using (StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream(), enc))
{
    requestWriter.Write(json);
    requestWriter.Close();
}
```

Comment: I can't do this. `GetRequestStream()` isn't part of WP8/Silverlight. I can only use BeginGetRequestStream which is what I am using.

Comment: I was mostly posting it for `var enc = new UTF8Encoding(false);
            webRequest.ContentLength = enc.GetByteCount(jsonData);` Should have narrowed it down sorry.